# How to use a java git submodule inside Play Framework?

Tags: java, git, playframework, git-submodules

I would like to use [org.openexchangerate.client](https://github.com/kgilmer/org.openexchangerate.client) in my Play 1 app.

Is there a proper way to use it as a git submodule, or must I download the files and embed them in my project, losing the connection to git?

Answer (score 0):

If the project you want to include is not hosted anywhere, you can add it to github and then reference that with a submodule.